# How to secure wp-api to prevent people add/remove posts?

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, wp-api

I am new to wp-api. 
I did install it and I am able to make some GET requests to retrieve content from my blog.

My question is very naive : can anyone send some DELETE/UPDATE rest requests to modify/delete my posts or must usre be authentificated first to do that ?

In other terms, can I use the wp-api as it is without any security considerations ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to WordPress REST Api version 2.7 above, you can't call PUT, PATCH, DELETE without being authenticated.

Here's more detail about the Authentication https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

You may also try to use POSTMAN to issue a PUT call to your API end point. You will be getting the like the one pasted below if you did not login.

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_edit",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```